# Rails 4: Maintain form inputs after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form on my `Locations#show` view for a different model (`PotentialClient`).  When my form fails validations, the redirect empties all fields because I need to initialize a new `potential_client` for the view to load.

**How can I change this so that after a failed validation, the fields populate?**

```
# LocationsController
def show
    @potential_client = PotentialClient.new
end

# class PotentialClient < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :name, :email, :phone

# PotentialClientsController
def create
    @potential_client = PotentialClient.new(potential_client_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @potential_client.save
            format.html { redirect_to Location.find(@potential_client.location_id), notice: 'Success!' }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to Location.find(@potential_client.location_id), notice: 'Failure!' }
        end
    end
end

# Form in /locations/show
<%= simple_form_for [ @location, @potential_client ] do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.input :message %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location.id %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are redirecting to another page, browser will send new request. So server wouldn't have any idea what happened in previous request. You need to use session to share data between requests

```
def show
  @potential_client = session[:potential_client] || PotentialClient.new
end


# PotentialClientsController
def create
  @potential_client = PotentialClient.new(potential_client_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @potential_client.save
      format.html { redirect_to Location.find(@potential_client.location_id), notice: 'Success!' }
    else
      session[:potential_client] = @potential_client
      format.html { redirect_to Location.find(@potential_client.location_id), notice: 'Failure!' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In order to make this work I also changed the line in `LocationsController` from `@potential_client = PotentialClient.new` to `@potential_client = session[:potential_client] || PotentialClient.new`.  If you add that to your response I'll mark it as correct

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the `Location.find(@potential_client.location_id)` to `@potential_client.location` which is quite a bit shorter and imho clearer.
Second thing: if you're only responding to html, the `respond_to` block might be redundant.